D&D Fighter (Brute) damage increase
I couldn't find anyone mentioning anything to do with this at all.
I am assuming it is definitely not how I'm reading it, however:
Why does it sound like the fighter brute stacks damage on every hit?
Just reading it sounds like every time you hit the weapon damage increases by an extra 1d* whatever the level.
This can't be a thing but has anyone else read it like that?

Just to confirm, are you asking about the Brute subclass from UA?
https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA-3Subclasses0108.pdf

Could you edit to add the text you're asking about to the question?  It's fine to post rules text that's specifically what you want to ask about, as long as you aren't like posting an entire class or something.

"I couldn't find anyone mentioning anything to do with this at all." — what "this" do you mean, exactly? Could you quote the relevant rules?

"it is definitely not how I'm reading it" - What are you reading and how are you reading it?

The boost is for that attack only
When the Brute Force feature from "Unearthed Arcana: Three Subclasses" says:

Whenever you hit with a weapon that you’re proficient with and deal damage, the weapon’s damage increases by an amount based on your level in this class.

...it means that the weapon damage is boosted for that attack. The weapon itself isn't boosted, but the damage for that attack. The extra damage die gets added to the damage dice portion of damage as described in the basic rules:

Each weapon, spell, and harmful monster ability specifies the damage it deals. You roll the damage die or dice, add any modifiers, and apply the damage to your target. Magic weapons, special abilities, and other factors can grant a bonus to damage.

For example if you are a level 3 Fighter (Brute) attacking with a greatsword, the weapon damage for that attack would be 2d6+1d4 instead of 2d6. You would then add an ability modifier or other modifiers as normal for weapon attacks.

I think this is the right answer, but it could be improved by giving a counter-example of the wording used in a feature that is cumulative to show OP that such language is not used here.  Also, you quote the Brute Force Feature but don't say where it is from.  It should be sourced, especially since OP has not made that attribution yet.

@Kirt Good point; cited

+1 . . . however, you don't actually say why.  It is unfortunate that the feature is worded the way that it is.  To the OP's point, it is worded such that it can be interpreted to mean the damage increases cumulatively.  The OP themselves gives the best argument against it: "This can't be a thing".  Allowing the damage increase to be cumulative would mean the brute rapidly scales to have more powerful hits than anything in the game.  That on the face of it is obviously absurd.  If an interpretation of the rules is obviously and completely absurd, then it can't be the right interpretation.

@Jack This is Unearthed Arcana content; it's not surprising that it has a poorly worded feature in it.
